# Xorg with Intel G41 videocard

Tags: debian, xorg, drivers

My PC has an integrated **Intel G41** video. I have been running Debian Squeeze for several years without any problems. Recently I upgraded to Wheezy and now after my computer wakes from sleep, X appears to be dead. In `Xorg.0.log` I see the following:

```
[  5123.481] (WW) intel(0): I830DRI2GetMSC:1457 get vblank counter failed: Invalid argument
[  5123.481] (WW) intel(0): I830DRI2ScheduleWaitMSC:1524 get vblank counter failed: Invalid argument
[  5131.489] (EE) intel(0): Detected a hung GPU, disabling acceleration.
[  5131.489] (EE) intel(0): When reporting this, please include i915_error_state from debugfs and the full dmesg.
[  5131.490] (WW) intel(0): I830DRI2GetMSC:1457 get vblank counter failed: Invalid argument
[  5131.490] (WW) intel(0): I830DRI2ScheduleWaitMSC:1524 get vblank counter failed: Invalid argument
```

I searched Google's and found suggestions to add `"DRI" "false"` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I tried that but then X only starts in "safe" mode.

Comment: Maybe the references [in this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=614124) are useful...[And the FAQ entry on old cards](http://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/faq/general.html) (i.e. [the fallback mentioned in the `README.Debian` file of `xserver-xorg-video-intel`](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=pkg-xorg/driver/xserver-xorg-video-intel.git;a=blob;f=debian/README.Debian) is available, using `fbdev` or `vesa`).

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a bug in the Xorg Intel driver. Issues like this will likely not find an answer here on StackExchange and instead need the expertise of the Intel Xorg developers. Please file a bug at http://bugs.freedesktop.org with the following properties:

Product: xorg

Component: Driver/intel

Include in the report your system's version of the X server and the Intel Xorg driver. Use your package manager to get that info. (I'm not a Debian user, so I can't help you there).

If you need an immediate answer, after filing the bug report I suggest bringing the issue to the attention of the Intel devs on IRC. You can find them in #intel-gfx on freenode.